# Trouble initializing empty directory with MediaStore

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, mediastore

Running SDK version 30, I'm working on an app that needs to stage some files (non-media. Binary files, text documents) accessible between two apps.

However, I'm having trouble creating this directory. I'm doing the following:

```
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + folderName)
val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
```

However, when I go to check whether the directory exists with:

```
val file = File(uri?.path)
Log.i(TAG, file.exists())
```

It returns false. Is this even possible? Even if the directory is created, can any application access it as long as it has the uri?

Comment: That is the wrong way using File class. You cannot use that uri for the File class. Have a look also at file.getAbsolutePath(). It will tell you an impossible path.

Comment: Use a file manager/explorer app on your device to see if the directory is created. Which i doubt... but that is another story..

Comment: Ah. Checking via the file explorer I see that the file definitely is created. Why can't File use that URI?

Comment: The file is created? I thought this was about creating a directory.

Comment: Ah yeah i meant directory

Comment: Your code does not create a directory here. Android version of used device?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't create a directory? If i go into Downloads/ I see that the folder folderName exists after this block runs